# How to hide asp.net technologies from Wappalyzer hosted on iis?

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis

I want to hide all information like angular, asp.net, iis version and ... on my website.
[wappalyzer image][1]

i added MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true; in Application_Start()
and HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server"); in Application_PreSendRequestHeaders
and  in web config.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAVe7.png

Comment: Each of them requires special setup, so use a search engine to find previous discussions. For the Server header alone you can read my post https://blog.lextudio.com/everything-you-might-need-about-iis-server-header-58ca268547be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide all the information, but you can hide the iis version, ASP.NET version, server type, etc.

- Hide the IIS version. The HTTP header “X-Powered-By” reveals the
  version of IIS used on the server. To stop this, remove the header:

  1. Open the IIS Manager.
  2. In the Connections tree, select the website that SS is running under.
  3. Click the HTTP Response Headers button on the right. The HTTP Response Headers panel appears.
  4. Click to select the X-Powered-By HTTP header.
  5. Click the Remove button in the Actions panel. The header disappears.
- Hide the ASP.NET version. The HTTP header “X-ASPNET-VERSION” reveals
  the version of ASP.NET being used by the SS application pool. To stop
  this, remove the header:

  1. Open the web.config file, which is located in the root directory for the website.
  2. Inside the <system.web> tag, add the tag .
  3. Save the file.
- Hide the server type. The HTTP header line Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 is added to
  the header by the .NET framework. To remove that information, you must update the
  Windows registry:

  1. Open the Windows Registry Editor.
  2. Navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters.
  3. Change the DisableServerHeader (REG_DWORD type) registry key from 0 to 1.